# Copying data from a file and changing the target every day using a date input

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have been inputing data in an Excel file everyday using a bunch of other Excel files. But now, I would like to start doing this automatically.

The first thing that I did was to create a code that would input the data that I need, but I have to change it every day because the day changes as well:

```
='C:\destination\[Archive2016-08-18.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1
```

I am having problems to edit this code to change the date "2016-08-18" from my input in those three other cells that I put the numbers on. Also, everyday it would fill the line below it, creating then a list of values as the days passes. I am also having troubles for doing it.

This does not look hard, but I am having lots of trouble while doing it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited
Add a helper column in Column B that is `=text(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")`
Then this formula in C1 `=INDIRECT("'[archive"&B1&".xlsx]Sheet1'!A1",TRUE)` assuming you have the date in cell A1. For some reason you cannot nest the text inside the indirect